# Find active remote machine connection of my PC

Tags: c#, event-viewer

I want to find current active remote machine ip address which is connected by my PC.

To explain it in better way let me tell you the scenario.

Laptop1 is my PC.

Laptop2 is my friend's PC.

`192.166.11.1` is server1.

`192.166.11.2` is server2.

`192.166.11.3` is server3.

Now, I want to build a software using C# which will install in Laptop1 and Laptop2 individually and that software will store details regarding active remote connection is going on for that particular PC not the server.

Let say if Laptop2 is using `192.166.11.2` server then my software will show that Laptop2 is using 192.166.11.2 machine same for Laptop1.

I am using `"Remote Desktop Connection"` to connect with my servers in windows OS.

Comment: Is the question how can you tell during a remote desktop session what ip address the remote machine connected from?

Comment: Will your software be able to handle multiple remote connections from the same laptop?

Comment: I don't quite see the point of your software. The software will monitor whether you have a remote connection, and if so, will let you know the IP address of the machine you are connected to, which you should already know... because you connected to it... or am I missing something?

Comment: @PeterAbolins
What you have understand is perfect. At my workplace we have 100 people and they use to connect remote machine so every time if I have to use that machine then I have to ask everyone that who is currently using the machine. So, I thought that if I build the small software which can be install on the every 100 people who are on the same network and then that software will share their username and IP address of the their active connected(Remote) machine. I will handle other part but I am unable to get the IP address.

Comment: What about doing it the other way? Write the software to run on the server, and then interrogate a service on the server to tell you who is connected. That way, you won't be relying on all the clients to report connection status.